# What is the best way to reference a post of another SE community?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, site-crossover

Suppose there are similar questions on the Stack Overflow. It is possible to flag one of the questions to report the question is a duplicate of another post. In this case a user who seeks a solution of a similar problem will see the message that helps to find the relevant topic:

> **This question already has an answer here:** ...

But what if such questions are asked on the different Stack Exchange communities? For example, the questions about the MySQL database system on the Stack Overflow and Database Administrators communities. I guess, one of the following should be done:

- Make a new answer that retells existing post.
- Make a new answer that contains the link to existing answer and short description of proposed solution.
- Add comment that contains the link to existing answer and short description of proposed solution.

I think the last variant is the best. But comments are not so helpful as
the above-mentioned message, because another user will not know the linked post solves question. Are there any community regulations and recommendations for the described case?

Comment: I’d go with your middle bullet. But I’m interested to see what consensus emerges. We just got a related question on EL&U Meta, which the answer to this question here might help resolve.

Comment: @DanBron See my answer. Feel free to use it on your meta :)

Comment: @DavidPostill Haha, we saw it and we’re already discussing it.

Comment: @DanBron Link please? :)

Comment: @DavidPostill Sure: [*Cross-post an answer from English Language Learners?*](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11052/55623).

Comment: @DanBron so wait, we're having a discussion about cross site duplicates, using a cross site duplicate post?

Comment: @jrh We’re actually having a meta discussion about Meta discussions... ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "Lets, there are"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen , my English is poor. Is *suppose* better than *let* in this case?

Comment: Related feature request: [Build and strengthen the Stack Exchange community with “crossover questions” between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199989/build-and-strengthen-the-stack-exchange-community-with-crossover-questions-bet)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### What if such questions are answered on a different Stack Exchange community?

You should provide a new answer on your own community which answers the question:

- Copy and rewrite (if necessary) the other answer.
- Quote appropriate parts of your answer and provide a link and attribution, as per the guidelines in [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing):

  > When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question (from
  >   another site or in an answer on Stack Overflow) make sure you do all
  >   of the following:
  >
  > - Provide a link to the original page or answer
  > - Quote only the relevant portion
  > - Provide the name of the original author
- Providing only a link is not sufficient as your comment or answer would become invalid if the linked page(s) change or are deleted (you cannot control whether question/answers on other sites are deleted).

  See [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/267099) for guidance on link only answers

In other words, treat it in the same way as if you had found an answer on an external site.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Is the post based on your own opinion or there are any community regulations (recommendations) for this case?

Comment: @Alexander The quoted bit pretty much answers your question and it is part of the help pages on every site :) Also I'm a moderator ...

Comment: @DavidPostill "I'm a moderator" without diamond is ... not very convincing (I see you are one on SU... but it required checking profile)